# Django VariableDoesNotExist exception on Eclipse PyDev when rendering template

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I just started a new Django project. At the moment I haven't written any code, just some tweaks on the settings file. I am using eclipse with PyDev and when I debug the app with eclipse, whenever I try to access to `http://localhost:8000/admin` the debugger catches a VariableDoesNotExist exception. If I resume the debugger, the page loads properly.

I've tried running `./manage.py runserver`, and then the page loads fine. It is also working on heroku.

This is a screenshot from Eclipse at the moment that the debugger stops:

[image: eclipse with pyDev]

I've been using Eclipse with pyDev for other Django projects and never had this problem before.

This is how my settings/base.py looks like:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'knb9js8(zm#1iu4&m64n249d+i7rk%%1(atevdp&c9fx4u)72*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                               'django.core.context_processors.request',
                               'django.core.context_processors.debug',
                               'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                               'django.core.context_processors.media',
                               'django.core.context_processors.static',
                               'django.core.context_processors.tz',
                               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages')

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pictures.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pictures.wsgi.application'


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I've also tried with the default value for `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I fix it:

1. On the caught Exception view, right-click on the exception and then `'Ignore ...'`
2. On PyDev > Manage Exception Breakpoints uncheck `Suspend on django template render exception` and make sure you don't have any of the checkboxes on the list selected.

Probably only 2 is needed, but this is what I did.